# Is there anyway I could get the song name from the current song playing using the Spotify Web Player?

Tags: jquery, iframe, spotify

I want to be able to get and display the current song name through javascript/jquery/etc on a web page that the embedded player is on, but not sure how I could do this with the issues relating to 'same origin policy'.

I have not written any javascript/jquery/etc code for this yet, because I just can't see how doing it would be possible. Essentially I am asking the question if this is something that could be achieved or not.

The base code I am starting out with is the following:
(Note: You will need a Spotify account to make the Spotify web player work)

```
<html>
<body>
<iframe src="https://embed.spotify.com/?uri=spotify:album:4INKaafecsV0LeBSwvVLaG" width="300" height="380" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What javascript/jquery/etc code have you written thus far, and what are the 'same origin policy' issues you're having?

Comment: Sorry, don't think I was as clear as I should have been in the initial problem description I've updated it. I haven't written any javascript/jquery code because I just can't see how this is possible. To my understanding the 'same origin policy' which I just learnt about while starting on this project doesn't allow to access information in iframes sitting on different domains.